# Image modelling/stiching

Tags: image, image-processing, panoramas

I was going through the [link](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2015/04/25/world/asia/nepal-landmarks-before-after-earthquake.html?_r=0) where NYTimes compared the Nepal before earthquake and after earthquake. Can anyone tell apart from photostiching/panorama and internet browser technology, What different different technologies have been used in creating this?

How can I learn about creating such stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pannellum](https://pannellum.org/) may be what you looking for. Created by Matthew using CSS or WebGL if supported for panorama visualisation.

I contributed some code and used it for example at my personal site.

A friend of mine is photographer and able to create the photos. You need someone to provide a true cubic/spheric or other panorama. There are several free ones for testing in the web. If you don't find something, I could provide you some test data. For stitching you can use open source Hugin which is utilised by pannellum as well.

To answer short:
- photographer & camera + special tripod + ca. 1h time
- stiching software like [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) to create a 2D Panorama source of six or more single images + capture one/photoshop/gimp + 1 - 5 h for retouching
- a viewing engine like pannellum or you can use 360° plugin for jQuery or similar to display that content

Comment: Thanks Mukarev. If my mobile gives me a feature to take a panaroma view. Do I need to do all above? Please let me know if I am misunderstanding something.